# How can I extract Regular Expression in JMeter for the following?

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

How can I extract only KK&JK from the following response in JMeter using Regular Expression Extractor?

```
<es2:ITEM>C2231597H88-KK&JK-M13122</es2:ITEM>
```

In the above response C2231597H88 is always 11 characters and M13122 is always 6 characters, but the number of characters for the value KK&JK in this example can change if that helps.

If I do `<es2:ITEM>(.+?)<` I get the whole thing C2231597H88-KK&JK-M13122, but I need to capture only KK&JK.

Comment: `<es2:ITEM>[A-Z\d]{11}-([^-]+)-[A-Z\d]{6}<`  ?

Comment: Try `<(es2:ITEM>)[^-<>]+-([^-<>]+)-[^<>]+</\1` and get capturing group 2 https://regex101.com/r/NvTG5z/1/ or `<es2:ITEM>[^-<>]+-([^-<>]+)-[^<>]+</es2:ITEM>` and get capture group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex pattern:

```
<es2:ITEM>[^-]+-([^-]+)-[^-]+</es2:ITEM>
```

And then check the first capture group, which should contain what you are trying to target.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match `KK&JK`, another option is to use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and get a match only:

```
(?<=<es2:ITEM>[A-Z0-9]{11}-)[^-<>]+(?=-[A-Z0-9]{6}</es2:ITEM>)
```

In parts

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not

  - `<es2:ITEM>[A-Z0-9]{11}- Match`` and 11 times A-Z or 0-9
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^-<>]+` Match 1+ times any char except `-` `<` or `>`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `-[A-Z0-9]{6}</es2:ITEM>` Match 6 times A-Z or 0-9 and `</es2:ITEM>`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bMUcnr/1)

Using 2 capturing groups you might get the value from the second capturing group and use a backreference to group 1 for the closing value:

```
<(es2:ITEM>)[A-Z0-9]{11}-([^-<>]+)-[A-Z0-9]{6}</\1
```

In Java double escape the backreference `\\1`